# Allow Office 2010 users to open docs from hyperlink in edit mode

Tags: workflow, tasks, hyperlink, word, webdav

I have SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow which assigns tasks to users. In the email of the task I have added a direct link to the related document.

I was originally using `[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%][Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]` as the hyperlink.

This was working fine for all users who had Microsoft Office 2013 installed. I ran into a problem when users with Microsoft Word 2010 clicked this link the document would open only in Read only mode - when they do have Edit rights on the document. The Enable Editing link was also not available.

I found a solution to add `ms-word:ofe|u|` to the hyperlink so now I'm using: 
`ms-word:ofe|u|[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%][Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]` as the hyperlink. This is great in that it gets the document to Edit mode however it gives the user a Security Notice pop-up (for all users, including Word 2010, Word 2013, and including for the site collection administrators).

Here is a screenshot of the security warning:
[image: Security Notice]

So then I found the following suggestion:
http://blog.amodit.com/2014/01/how-to-make-webdav-work-in-read-write.html

However it's not working. People are still getting the Security Notice.

Any suggestions to avoid this security notice and just open the files in Edit mode from a hyperlink in an email?

Comment: You are right, this is regulated on Office suite desktop application side. Can you post a screenshot of security notice please?

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post in Office_Integration_&_Sharepoint blog at Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_integration__sharepoint/archive/2014/12/04/force-microsoft-word-to-open-in-edit-mode-from-hyperlink-in-an-email.aspx). Follow instructions in p.6:

> 6. You can make this warning go away by adding one of the two following registry keys, 14 is for Office 2010 and 15 is for Office 2013
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications\ms-word:`
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications\ms-word:`

---

In fact, [KB925757](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925757) describes a registry manipulations that affect those warnings in Office. You can use information in "How to enable or disable hyperlink warnings per protocol" section to turn off warnings for `ms-word:` protocol. Or disable them completely. Protocol-level settings are surely more preferred.

Comment: This looks promising Aziz. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will. You might want to revert changes proposed by http://blog.amodit.com/2014/01/how-to-make-webdav-work-in-read-write.html. And always take backups when altering registry. Once the solution's confirmed to work, admins can make GPO in AD to avoid manual changes to each machine. Ping me if you need help with that

Comment: I don't have the "Office" tree at all in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft location in the Registry Editor.

Comment: Just create everything that is required. This is documented, therefore supported. See http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9D9s-LT_3AA/URfTc4zR1EI/AAAAAAAAB24/5gTmgn-HXZg/s1600/EVregistry.png, but you'll have `ms-word:` at the last one

Comment: @Maureen Did that work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to add the Office registry tree items and am waiting for support on that. Thanks for checking in.

Comment: Hope this helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pq1wMhRDxQQ

Comment: Editing the registry is not an option (organizationally) therefore we've decided to accept the security warning. Now though, many users are now first prompted for "Choose a program", and then a "Could not open 'ms-word:ofe|u|https://intranet/site/Documents/File.docx' Microsoft Word error when clicking on the link. The user does have permission to open the file from within SharePoint directly. Users may not have admin rights on their computers. We just want people to be able to click a link from within an Outlook email to a Word document in SharePoint. This should not be so complicated.